# How do I Create Azure Static Web App with Visual Studio?

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, web, azure-static-web-app

I want to create an Azure Static Web App, aka (No server side code/Razor/MVC etc.) that consists of a single index.html and site.css sheet with Visual Studio 2022 and then deploy those two resources to an Azure Static Web App.

I have worked through the basic VS Code, GitHub sample and deployed successfully. I'm satisfied I understand the concept.

How would you create and push a project from Visual Studio 2022 to a Static Web App?

I have not been able to recreate the same scenario using Visual Studio. All the projects will set you up for ASP.net Core/MVC/Razor/Blazor etc. If you use the simple "Blank" project, what would I add manually to create a simple web page that can be run in a browser, then, pushed to GitHub then to a Azure Static Web App instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bring back the ASP.NET Web Application Project Selections the way you had it in previous version of Visual Studio prior to 2022, do the following:

*This is useful for developing web apps using the Visual Studio 2022 IDE that you plan to deploy to Azure Static Web Apps (serverless), this does not apply to Visual Studio Code.*

**Follow These Steps:**

1. Start the Visual Studio Installer app
2. Select Modify
3. Select the Individual Components tab
4. Check Option: .NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack *(or your appropriate version)*
5. Check Option: .NET Framework project and item templates
6. Complete the updated install
7. Start Visual Studio 2022
8. Start New Project, Select or search for: "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)"
9. Name your Project & Solution

On the next screen, you will now find the missing options under "Create a new ASP.NET Web Application"

- Empty
- Web Forms
- MVC
- Web API
- Single Page Application

Apparently the project selection templates changed between Visual Studio 2019 & 2022. Note that all the other project templates in the current version of Visual Studio 2022 are based on various server side or Blazor technologies. We had lost the simple Web Application choices.

*For reference, I provide this answer as of Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.8.6*